# Using classes with only static methods for organizational purposes?

Tags: python, class, static-methods

I work for a MSSP and a lot of the security alerts we deal with, especially with new clients, can be dealt with according to some simple if-then logic without taking up analyst time to research. To handle these sorts of alerts, I am building a basic python program with a series of logic tests to see if a given alert falls into a 'known' category and can be dealt with automatically.

My desired format is to have a separate python file for each client we service for organizational purposes, and within each file have a series of conditions with corresponding actions if the conditions are met. A managing script then ingests alert data, runs it through every condition within the corresponding client's file, and when a condition returns `True` it passes the data onto the corresponding action function. So my question is how to organize this.

Currently, within a client's file, I have a class for each 'known' condition, with two `@staticmethod` functions: condition() and action(). Then the managing script's logic is effectively [pseudocode]:

```
for class in client_file:
    if class.condition(alert_data):
        class.action(alert_data)
```

Organizationally, I like this. Each client has a file, and each known thing to look for has a class. My hesitation, is I am not sure if this is 'pythonic' or generally kosher. I am using `@staticmethod`s because I  don't need these classes to have multiple instances, I just like the organizational ability of grouping functions into classes for logical relevance, but it still looks a bit strange and I'm worried it could cause confusion.

So I'm interested in the community's opinion, does this seem like an okay organizational method for my application, or do you have any suggestions on better ways of keeping everything neat?

Example class:

```
class HostIsWindows:
    @staticmethod
    def condition(alert_data):
        if 'os_type' in alert and alert['os_type'] == 'windows':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def action(alert_data):
        ... do something ...
        return "This is a result message."
```

Comment: Note that you *weren't* advised to post this on SO - I'd recommend reviewing [ask] for the relevant site before writing your question.

Comment: Sorry that disclaimer was confusing, you are right - upon further review of Code Review's 'How to Ask' I made the logical jump that SO was a better sight because I am not asking for assistance with finished code but rather on a best-practice, which seems to be a SO question. I have removed the disclaimer.

Comment: Are each Class's condition and actions unique to the class?  are those conditions/actions unique to each client - eg is `HostIsWindows.condition()` the same for each client? and is `HostIsWindows.action()` different than `SomeOtherClass.action()`?

Comment: I would just use the module itself. Modules are essentially static-classes which are singleton's to boot. I suppose it comes down to a matter of taste, but a class with all staticmethods screams "I should just be a module" to me.

Comment: @wwii Yes in most cases to both. The most common use case is if a client says they use a given software under a condition (e.g. remote desktop to a certain IP) then we know it is safe to ignore that software for that client for that condition.

Comment: What you're doing by using classes this way is essentially using them as namespace, which isn't intrinsically a bad thing—far from it—but you're not taking advantage of them either.

Comment: @jaunpa.arrivillaga I considered that, but with potentially numerous condition/action pairs per client having a separate module for each seems messier than necessary

Comment: @martineau not taking advantage of the abilities of classes is I think what's causing my hesitation, I just don't know if there's a better way to add the same organizational clarity without inducing too much confusion to an outside developer

Comment: I was just tying to figure out if it would make sense to define all the functions in one module and import them as necessary into each client's module.

Comment: @wwii I do plan to have a shared utility file for common functions (e.g. download a pcap or fetch information from VirusTotal) but most conditions/actions are going to be unique so I think having the bulk of the logic within client files will be easier to follow

Comment: Eric: Using them will often actually makes things simpler because it take less code to do what you want instead of lots of almost-the-same snippets in each `class` that you define (and won't remain intimidating once you get the hang of them). BTW, you can't use the reserved word `class` as the name of a variable like you have in the line `for class in client_file:`.

Comment: @martineau to clarify, by "them" are you referring to separate modules? About using the keyword `class`: I realize that wouldn't work, it is just pseudocode to easily illustrate the idea - I labeled it as such to make that more clear.

Comment: No I'm talking about classes. Classes will let you factor-out common code that can be reused for each instance so there will be less of it. The only thing that will vary from one class instance to another will be the _data_ the code operates upon—this data is typically referenced through the argument named `self` each method automatically receives as their first argument. i.e. `self.foobar = 42`.